# Isolation Level vs Optimistic Locking-Hibernate , JPA

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a web application where I want to ensure concurrency with a DB level lock on the object I am trying to update. I want to make sure that a batch change or another user or process may not end up introducing inconsistency in the DB.

I see that Isolation levels ensure read consistency and optimistic lock with `@Version` field can ensure data is written with a consistent state.

My question is can't we ensure consistency with isolation level only? By making my any transaction that updates the record Serializable(not considering performance), will I not ensure that a proper lock is taken by the transaction and any other transaction trying to update or acquire lock or this transaction will fail?
Do I really need version or timestamp management for this?

Answer (score 13):

Depending on isolation level you've chosen, specific resource is going to be locked until given transaction commits or rollback - it can be lock on a whole table, row or block of sql. It's a pessimistic locking and it's ensured on database level when running a transaction.

Optimistic locking on the other hand assumes that multiple transactions rarely interfere with each other so no locks are required in this approach. It is a application-side check that uses `@Version` attribute in order to establish whether version of a record has changed between fetching and attempting to update it.

It is reasonable to use optimistic locking approach in web applications as most of operations span through multiple HTTP request. Usually you fetch some information from database in one request, and update it in another. It would be very expensive and unwise to keep transactions open with lock on database resources that long. That's why we assume that nobody is going to use set of data we're working on - it's cheaper. If the assumption happens to be wrong and version has changed in between requests by someone else, Hibernate won't update the row and will throw `OptimisticLockingException`. As a developer, you are responsible for managing this situation.

Simple example. Online auctions service - you're watching an item page. You read its description and specification. All of it takes, let's say, 5 minutes. With pessimistic locking and some isolation levels you'd block other users from this particular item page (or all of the items even!). With optimistic locking everybody can access it. After reading about the item you're willing to bid on it so you click the proper button. If any other of users watching this item and change its state (owner changed its description, someone other bid on it) in the meantime you will probably (depending on app implementation) be informed about the changes before application will accept your bid because version you've got is not the same as version persisted in database.

Hope that clarifies a few things for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But again Is Isolation level actually Pessimistic lock behind the scenes? and what if I do have Isolation level serialized and trow transactions are started. Will one of them be blocked or I can expect some exception from hibernate similar to Optimistic lock Exception?

Comment: Yes, basically using isolation level higher than read uncommited on your transaction you do a pessimistic locking. You put a lock on the resource you're using whether someone else need it or not. With serialized isolation level you won't get any exception it'll just lock the whole table you're working on and other transaction will have to wait to access it.

Comment: Imagine REST application from the example I gave you in my answer. Would it be right to lock whole table of items (meaning any other user application wouldn't be allowed to get a view of any item!) with with serializable isolation in order to allow one user to bid on an item? You have to distinguish transaction in your code and transaction from user's point of view (which usually means many requests in a web application). Take a look at conversations (http://what-when-how.com/hibernate/implementing-conversations-hibernate/) maybe it'll brighten things up.

Comment: Your answer is a bit different from the other comment which talks about PessimisticLockException. i guess this is configurable in hibernate. One last thing though, about the other isolation levels eg. repeatable read , They sound close to optimistic lock or are those also pessimistic. Am I right on that ?

Comment: if not then is it that hibernate is always using pessimistic locking whenever we use some isolation level?

Comment: I'm not sure about what db you were talking about but according to [this description of serializable in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) it will actually behave more like optimistic lock - raising errors rather than locking. Locking has to be done with SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Answer (score 3):

Unless we are talking about some small, isolated web application (only app that is working on a database), then making all of your transactions to be Serializable would mean having a lot of confidence in your design, not taking into account the fact that it may not be the only application hitting on that certain database.

In my opinion the incorporation of Serializable isolation level, or a Pessimistic Lock in other words, should be very well though decision and applied for:

- Large databases and short transactions that update only a few rows
- Where the chance that two concurrent transactions will modify the same rows is relatively low.
- Where relatively long-running transactions are primarily read-only.

Based on my experience, in most of the cases using just the Optimistic Locking would be the most beneficial decision, as frequent concurrent modifications mostly happen in only small percentage of cases.
Optimistic locking definately also helps other applications run faster (dont think only of yourself!).

So when we take the Pessimistic - Optimistic locking strategies spectrum, in my opinion the truth lies somewhere more towards the Optimistic locking with a flavor of serializable here and there.

I really cannot reference anything here as the answer is based on my personal experience with many complex web projects and from my notes when i was preapring to my JPA Certificate.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!
Does that mean that behind the scenes ISOLATION LEVEL (SERIALIZABLE) actually acquires a pessimistic lock before beginning the transaction?
And what about other isolation levels specially the REPEATABLE READ. Is this also pessimistic lock at a row level?

Comment: When it comes to JPA, it does not allow to choose the isolation level directly, unless you unwrap the API and use vendor specific configuration and hints (that api sometimes supports). When you acquire pessimistic lock you automatically prevent non-repeatable read and phantom reads.

Comment: But Hibernate and Spring allows you to set the ISOLATION Level as property before you begin a transaction. So this must be internally taking a transaction lock and this must be a pessimistic lock. If in my update method I say ISOLATION level is SERIALIZABLE, will it not guarantee that no other update is possible during that time if my transaction in fact got the lock?

Comment: You can do it in hibernate thats true, but not in JPA (its always better to use the API instead of implementation but that is your choice of course). Answer to your question is YES, after isolating with serializable any operation on entity means acquiring a phisical lock on the database and until the transaction is commited, no other transaction can access that particular row / table. If other transaction is working on that row when you try to access it with Serializable isolation level, you will get a PessimisticLockException and your transaction will be rolled back (as of JPA specification).