# Hibernate resource locking

Tags: java, hibernate, locking

I've been searching the net on how to fix/minimize the occurrence of race condition within a web application using hibernate. And I came across that using the `LockMode.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE` would be suitable in my case since there are numbers/figures involved that needs to be updated within our 4 servers that are connected to a single database.

Now I am trying to develop a unified server that responsible to save/update/delete data into the database. And I am confused on when to use the locking mechanism? Should I always lock the resource? Or just when I needed to update it?

For example:

Update function will be locking the resource of the `User` table, will the request be able to retrieve the data even if it uses a query without locking?

Comment: be wary of using pessimistic locking all the time. Maybe its better to consider a mix of optimistic / pessimistic locking. Check out my answer here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751192/isolation-level-vs-optimistic-locking-hibernate-jpa/41752188#41752188

Comment: @MaciejKowalski right now I just read an article the power of the two. I'am starting to consider the combination of the two locks. All the on-hold request to the resource are executed sequentially when the lock is released right?

Comment: I dont think there is a definite answer to that.. same as with java multithreding... almost impossible to predict which thread get the resource after the release.. In this case this would be based on how the database driver behaves.. but i doubt you could know for sure

Comment: I think so too. I'll just read a few more articles to support the possible mechanism.